# How is IntPtr Marshalled?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, intptr

Until recently I thought that marshalling an `IntPtr` in P/Invoke would just involve a 'blitting' operation; i.e. simply copying the pointer from e.g. C++ to C#.

However I was talking to someone recently that mentioned there was more to it than that. He specifically mentioned that the `IntPtr` marshalling takes in to account **byte order** (i.e. little-endian or big-endian). That seems strange to me though: Surely the byte order wouldn't matter unless we were sending the pointer over to another machine, and god knows why you'd do that?

Can anyone here shed a little more light on this for me; and possibly link to some resource for further reading? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a straight blit, no different conceptually from `int` or `long`. Obviously it's 4 bytes under x86, and 8 bytes under x64. There's no magic here.

Endianness is never an issue with p/invoke marshalling. The endianness is a property of the underlying machine. The unmanaged DLL that you call using p/invoke using the same endianness as your managed code, because they run on the same machine.

Comment: Yup, that would seem to be all there is to it